# How to create a degree correlation matrix for a network

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to create a degree correlation matrix for a network, where the columns and rows capture the degrees of the network. I am not looking for a global measure--like assortativity_degree(), but an actual correlation matrix, where each element in the matrix is the number of edges that exist in the graph for nodes with degree = whatever and degree = whatever. I have dug around in the igraph documentation and Googled but nothing quite gets to what I want. I have cobbled together the following, which seems to work, but I'm wondering if there is a more straightforward method that I'm ignorant. I don't think what I'm after is so esoteric that no one else has thought about it--and perhaps there is a function in igraph or the like and I just don't quite know what it's called.

```r
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union

g <- make_graph("Zachary")

x <- sort(unique(degree(g))) # vector of all degrees in the network
y <- sort(unique(degree(g))) # vector for all degrees in the network

datalist = list()

# this loop creates a vector that identifies the number of 
# edges that occur between nodes of degree whatever and degree whatever
for(i in y) {               
 row <- mapply(function(x) 
 {length(E(g)[V(g)[degree(g) == i] %--% V(g)[degree(g) == x]])},
 x)      
 datalist[[i]] <- row 
}

# takes the data list created in the previous for loop and row bind it into a 
# matrix
m = do.call(rbind, datalist)

# label rows and columns with the relevatn degree
rownames(m) <- unique(sort(degree(g)))
colnames(m) <- unique(sort(degree(g)))

m
#>    1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10 12 16 17
#> 1  0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  1  0
#> 2  0 0 0 3 0 1 2  1  5  3  7
#> 3  0 0 2 3 1 3 1  1  0  3  2
#> 4  0 3 3 1 3 1 2  2  2  3  3
#> 5  0 0 1 3 0 1 1  2  2  2  3
#> 6  0 1 3 1 1 0 1  1  1  2  1
#> 9  0 2 1 2 1 1 0  1  0  1  0
#> 10 0 1 1 2 2 1 1  0  1  1  0
#> 12 0 5 0 2 2 1 0  1  0  0  1
#> 16 1 3 3 3 2 2 1  1  0  0  0
#> 17 0 7 2 3 3 1 0  0  1  0  0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do something like below by creating a graph of degrees, i.e., `g.dg`

```
dg <- degree(g)
g.dg <- graph_from_data_frame(
    with(
        get.data.frame(g),
        data.frame(dg[from], dg[to])
    ),
    directed = FALSE
)
mat <- get.adjacency(g.dg, sparse = FALSE)
ord <- order(as.numeric(row.names(mat)))
out <- mat[ord, ord]
```

which gives

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10 12 16 17
1  0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  1  0
2  0 0 0 3 0 1 2  1  5  3  7
3  0 0 2 3 1 3 1  1  0  3  2
4  0 3 3 1 3 1 2  2  2  3  3
5  0 0 1 3 0 1 1  2  2  2  3
6  0 1 3 1 1 0 1  1  1  2  1
9  0 2 1 2 1 1 0  1  0  1  0
10 0 1 1 2 2 1 1  0  1  1  0
12 0 5 0 2 2 1 0  1  0  0  1
16 1 3 3 3 2 2 1  1  0  0  0
17 0 7 2 3 3 1 0  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: This is genius. Thank you. Can you explain to me what is going on inside the with() function? What I'm seeing is that it's applying the data. frame function to the the edge list from the graph--but I can't sort out what that is doing conceptually speaking.

Comment: @avgoustisw You see that `get.data.frame(g)` has two columns, `from` and `to`. Using `with`, we enter the environment of `get.data.frame(g)` and can use `from` and `to` as names of data (rather than `get.data.frame(g)$from` or `get.data.frame(g)$to`). If you type `?with`, you will see more example and explanation.